# How to call different controller function for same route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a route defined for submitting loan application, what i want to do is call different controller function based on the amount of loan the user is applying for.

```
app.use('/submitLoanRequest50kMore', mw1, mw2, mw3, loan50kLess)

app.use('/submitLoanRequest50kMore', mw1, mw2, mw3, loan50kMore)
```

What i want is that the end point be the same and i call controller function (loan50kLess or loan50kMore) based on onw of the middleware say mw4

```
app.use('/submitLoanRequest', mw1, mw2, mw3, mw4, .....) // could be loan50kLess() or loan50kMore()
```

I know this can be done by writing the logic in the last function or route forwarding, but this thing can also be nested to multiple level such as i can add different middleware if loan amount is more than `50k`.

Please let me know if there is a way to do this in node, express is not necessary.

Also let me know if you need clarification.
`It's called a rule engine or workflow engine in java`

Answer (score 0):

You can implement such behaviour with express [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html). ([also](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html)) 
As I see, you already use middlewares, so to add the new one you have to create function like this:

```
// function accepts three params. request, response and next. 
const loan50kLess = (req, res, next) => {
  //assume you have load parameter somewhere in request param.
  // example logic would be this

  if(req.params.loan > 50000) { 
    return res.status(200).json({message: 'Load is more then 50k'}) 
 }
 // If load is less then 50k, or any other middleware param, you have just call next() to pass execution to the next stage.
 next()
}
```

And then in your route you can use it as another middleware:

```
app.use('/submitLoanRequest50kMore', mw1, mw2, mw3, loan50kMore);
```

But note, if in this case the loan is less than 50k, you have to add logic to middleware, or to add next function in your call to process this case.
Like this:

```
app.use('/submitLoanRequest50kMore', mw1, mw2, mw3, loan50kMore, (req, res) => {
  ...some logic if loan is less then 50k
})
```